# Change Android Tag-Manager Language If user changes app Language, not device language

Tags: android, android-preferences, google-tag-manager

I am Implementing Tag manager in my app I want to change language of tag-manager value as soon as user changes app language which he can do by single button click in my app.

If user is changing phone language then it is working fine but I want to make it work when user change app language(not phone language).

In my app this is how I am changing language.

```
 public void setLocal() {

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    String languageSetting = Utility.getLanguageSetting();
    String localeSaved = new Locale("en").getLanguage();
    if (languageSetting.equalsIgnoreCase("hindi")) {
        localeSaved = new Locale("hi").getLanguage();
    }

    config.locale = new Locale(localeSaved);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code like you, it works well. The difference is I recreate the activities after I change the language, and I also put some code to `Application`'s `onCreate()` method to change the language before all activities create.

```
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    if (!config.locale.equals(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE)){
        config.locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, metrics);
    } else {
        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, metrics);
    }
    recreate();
```

Comment: is it working perfectly with tag-manager ?? Mine is working perfectly but not with tag-manager(for tag-manager to accept change I need o change language of phone)

Answer (score 0):

**"Tag manager Language change"** only works when user change language of Phone which is very bad for user 
This is How I achieved 
  1. I created only one variable on Tag manager
  2. Created single json for both language
  3. 
        `{
        'text': 'Welcome',
        'text_hindi': 'वेलकम'
     }`
 4. Inside app

```
  /* get text for welcome based on app language*/
 public String getText(boolean isEnglish) {
    String text = null;
    if (isEnglish) {
     text = getTagContainerHolder().getTagContainer().getString("text");
     } else {
   text = getTagContainerHolder().getTagContainer().getString("text_hindi");
    }
    return text;
}

 /* This is how i change language of my app when user click button*/
 public void setLocal(boolean isEnglish) {
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    String localeSaved = new Locale("en").getLanguage();
    if (!isEnglish) {
        localeSaved = new Locale("hi").getLanguage();
    }

    config.locale = new Locale(localeSaved);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Now I can change my welcome text dynamically from tag manager even after shipping my app on play store